# NPM weekly downloads is zero

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, reactjs, npm

[image: npm]
[image]
Why the weekly downloads are zero for all the packages in npm?new here Why this is in hold the question seems clear ?

> **If you can please open this issue,I don't know how to do it thanks** [here-npm](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues)

I've found a link to **check status** when it will be repaired [get status](https://status.npmjs.org/)

Comment: Though I also personally noticed this and I am curious to know, this isn't the right forum to ask this kind of questions. Read more here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @SunilBN i don't know much about other forum so i posted here

Comment: anyone figure out what's going on with this yet?

Comment: no , please tweet about it at @npm_support

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I observed the stats issue as well and checked two days ago.  Read [NPM monthly and weekly downloads](https://github.com/badges/shields/issues/939) Issue on Github.

I checked by query https://api.npmjs.org/downloads/range/2018-05-20:2018-06-06/uuid

It seems like the stats are broken since May 29th, 2018

```
 {
      "downloads": 467935,
      "day": "2018-05-27"
    },
    {
      "downloads": 284932,
      "day": "2018-05-28"
    },
    {
      "downloads": 52,
      "day": "2018-05-29"
    },
    {
      "downloads": 0,
      "day": "2018-05-30"
    },
    {
      "downloads": 0,
      "day": "2018-05-31"
    }
```